# Given a Adjacency Matrix Table, complete an adjacency List

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I'm given the table: 
(An Adjacency matrix of a graph)

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c}& \text{d}& \text{e}& \text{f} & \text{g}\\ \hline
\text{a} & x & 7& &5\\ \hline
\text{b} & 7& x &8 &9&7 \\ \hline
\text{c} & &8&x&&5 \\ \hline
\text{d} &5&9&&x&15&6\\ \hline
\text{e} &&7&5&15&x&8&9 \\ \hline
\text{f} &&&&6&8&x&11\\ \hline
\text{g} &&&&&9&11&x\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And I'm told to complete the adjacenty list below
Where all the blank spaces in the table are filled with infinity.
a.      b, 7      d, 5

I'm not sure how to go about approaching this, since I'm not given the graph, but only the adjacency table. Any ideas?

Comment: What do the numbers in the table correspond to?

Comment: I'm not told, all I'm told is to consider the table and all the blank spaces are  filled with infinity. And the table is an adjacency matrix of a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an example of an adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph that is not simple. Each entry $A_{ij}$ in the matrix corresponds to the number of edges between vertices $i$ and $j$. For example, there are 5 edges between $a$ and $d$, since $A_{a,d}=5$. If $A_{ij}$ is a blank entry, then there are no edges between vertices $i$ and $j$. From this, it should not be too difficult to determine what the graph looks like.

The *adjacency list* of a graph is the list of vertices of the graph along with all of their neighbors. Vertices $i$ and $j$ are considered *neighbors* if $A_{ij}\neq0$. The first entry in the adjacency list would be
$$
a:b,d
$$
since $a$ is adjacent to $b$ and $d$. Can you fill in the rest?

Comment: Okay, but how do i go about completing the adjacency list, assuming I can now draw out the graph? (I'm not sure what is meant by the adjacency list).

Comment: See the addition to my answer :)